an import that works on python, but not on jupyter lab
I have installed a library (https://pypi.org/project/plot-likert/) in a venv, but curiously it works on vanilla python and does not work on jupyter lab
On vanilla python:
(venv_jupyter) lucas@karaboudjan:~/.instalados/venv_jupyter$ which python
/home/lucas/.instalados/venv_jupyter/bin/python
(venv_jupyter) lucas@karaboudjan:~/.instalados/venv_jupyter$ python
Python 3.10.12 (main, Sep 11 2024, 15:47:36) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import plot_likert
>>> 

On jupyter lab (even after a kill -9 -1 and running everything again)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 4
      2 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      3 import seaborn as sns
----> 4 import plot_likert
      5 health = pd.read_csv('health_concerns.csv')
      6 health.head()

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plot_likert'

I have no idea what might be the issue! Other libraries are working as intended after a pip install

As a troubleshooting step, I suggest you follow the advice on this post (P. Camilleri's answer) and check whether the notebook's output matches your which python result

@Wayne I'd think that the more principled solution is to make sure that Jupyter and the command line are using the same kernel

In this case, sorting that out would be more thorough. But sometimes an option to get past a hurdle can help. I'll reword: if you aren't having much luck  & you haven't already tried it, you may want to try %pip install plot-likert. See more about the modern %pip install command here.  (It works where I tried but using that gives warnings as the code uses deprecated methods, even if I use the development one.)

@Wayne Fair enough
